What should template constructor of allocator do
I'm learning allocators and I have found that MSVC demand of presence of template constructor for allocator (and g++ and clang do not), here is minimal example of code that triggers error:
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct ContiguousAllocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    ContiguousAllocator() noexcept {}
    //template<class U>
    //ContiguousAllocator(const ContiguousAllocator<U>& v) noexcept
    //{}
    ~ContiguousAllocator() noexcept
    {}

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {}
};

template<class T, class U>
constexpr bool operator==(const ContiguousAllocator<T>&, const ContiguousAllocator<U>&) noexcept
{
    return false;
}

template<class T, class U>
constexpr bool operator!=(const ContiguousAllocator<T>&, const ContiguousAllocator<U>&) noexcept
{
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int, ContiguousAllocator<int>> vector;
    std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>, ContiguousAllocator<std::pair<const int, int>>> map;

    return 0;
}


Uncommenting template constructor for type U removes error. And the error is following:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>' to 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>'
          with
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,int>,void *>
          ]
          and
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): note: 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>::ContiguousAllocator': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
          with
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
          ]
  C:\User\Code\main.cpp(56): note: could be 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>::ContiguousAllocator(const ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst> &)'
          with
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): note: 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>::ContiguousAllocator(const ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>' to 'const ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst> &'
          with
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
          ]
          and
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,int>,void *>
          ]
          and
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>' to 'const ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>'
          with
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,int>,void *>
          ]
          and
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): note: while trying to match the argument list '(ContiguousAllocator<_Newfirst>)'
          with
          [
              _Newfirst=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,int>,void *>
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
  C:\User\Code\main.cpp(61): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<int,int,std::greater<int>,ContiguousAllocator<std::pair<const int,int>>>' being compiled
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\map(72): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Kty=int,
              _Ty=int,
              _Pr=std::greater<int>,
              _Alloc=ContiguousAllocator<std::pair<const int,int>>
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1071): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::~_Tree(void) noexcept'
          with
          [
              _Kty=int,
              _Ty=int,
              _Pr=std::greater<int>,
              _Alloc=ContiguousAllocator<std::pair<const int,int>>
          ]
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\map(369): note: see the first reference to 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::~_Tree' in 'std::map<int,int,std::greater<int>,ContiguousAllocator<std::pair<const int,int>>>::~map'
          with
          [
              _Kty=int,
              _Ty=int,
              _Pr=std::greater<int>,
              _Alloc=ContiguousAllocator<std::pair<const int,int>>
          ]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1075): error C2530: '_Alproxy': references must be initialized
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1076): error C3536: '_Alproxy': cannot be used before it is initialized
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1076): error C2672: '_Delete_plain_internal': no matching overloaded function found
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xmemory(1112): note: could be 'void std::_Delete_plain_internal(_Alloc &,_Alloc::value_type *const ) noexcept'
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1076): note: Failed to specialize function template 'void std::_Delete_plain_internal(_Alloc &,_Alloc::value_type *const ) noexcept'
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1076): note: With the following template arguments:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xtree(1076): note: '_Alloc=int'

Update: yes, probably Godbolt has some different default parameters. Here are mine:
FAILED: Allocator/CMakeFiles/Allocator.dir/Allocator.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1440~1.338\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++20 -ZI /showIncludes /FoAllocator\CMakeFiles\Allocator.dir\Allocator.cpp.obj /FdAllocator\CMakeFiles\Allocator.dir\ /FS -c C:\User\Code\Allocator\Allocator\Allocator.cpp


Can't replicate https://godbolt.org/z/hvxa5aK4T. Need more details about how you compile that code.

That template constructor is a converting constructor allowing to "convert" a ContiguousAllocator<std::string> into a ContiguousAllocator<int> (or for map,to its internal Node type)

If MSVC demands it it is probably because it is mandated by the spec (The entry for A a(b) )
